# Unicode characters not shown properly when generating XML

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle11g

I have this package. This package generates an XML file and export it to various stores. But I have come across a scenario where in if the employee name is of a special character something like 'Rïçhàrd Bæcôn' the XML generates it as 'Richard B?con'.

```
CREATE OR replace PACKAGE BODY
  my_pkg
AS
FUNCTION Get_emp
  RETURN T_XFORM_STRING
IS
  PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
  emp_data_string T_XFORM_STRING := T_xform_string();
  line_counter NUMBER := 1;
  v_text       VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL;
  v_rowcnt     NUMBER := 0;
  emp_rec EMP_REC_TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT Count(*)
  INTO   v_rowcnt
  FROM   nbty_custom ;

  IF ( v_rowcnt > 0 ) THEN
    OPEN emp_cur;
    FETCH emp_cur bulk collect
    INTO  emp_rec.emp_id,
          emp_rec.emp_name,
          emp_rec.emp_city;

    CLOSE emp_rec;
    FOR i IN 1..emp_rec.emp_id.Count()
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        SELECT
               CASE
                      WHEN emp_rec.Emp_id(i) IN('001',
                                                '002',
                                                '003') THEN '    <Employee>        '
                                    ||Chr(10)
                                    || '        <EmployeeID>'
                                    ||emp_rec.Emp_id(i)
                                    ||'</EmployeeID>'
                                    ||Chr(10)
                                    || '        <EmployeeName>'
                                    ||emp_rec.Emp_name(i)
                                    ||'</EmployeeName>'
                                    ||Chr(10)
                                    || '        <EmployeeCity>'
                                    ||emp_rec.Emp_city(i)
                                    ||'</EmployeeCity>'
                                    ||Chr(10)
                                    || '    </Employee>        '
                                    ||Chr(10)
                                    ||
               end
        into   v_text
        FROM   dual;--emp_data_string.extend;
        Emp_data_string(line_counter) :=v_text;
        line_counter:=line_counter+1;
      END;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
  RETURN emp_data_string;
END get_emp;
END my_pkg;
```

I have tried using htf.escape_sc() function. But still not getting the same format. I want to display as 'Rïçhàrd Bæcôn' in XML as well.

Can any one please help?

Comment: What are your database and national character sets? What data types are your table columns?

Comment: Its Oracle 11g and <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> and data type is varachar2